# Terraform fail due output for_each values

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When I trying to dynamically allocate subnet ids by running this tf file:

```
  data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

  resource "aws_vpc" "wpl_vpc" {
    cidr_block             = var.vpc_cidr
    enable_dns_hostnames   = true
      tags = {
          Name             = "WPL-VPC"
          CreatedBy        = var.created_by
      }
  }
  resource "aws_subnet" "wpl_public_subnet" {
    for_each                = { for index, az_name in data.aws_availability_zones.available.names : index => az_name }
    vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.wpl_vpc.id
    cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, each.key + 10)
    availability_zone       = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[each.key]
    map_public_ip_on_launch = true
      tags = {
          Name              = "WPL-PublicSubnet"
          CreatedBy         = var.created_by
      }
  }
  output "wpl_public_subnet_ids" {
  value = [aws_subnet.wpl_public_subnet.*.id]
  }
```

I get an error:

```
     Error: Unsupported attribute
       on ../modules/vpc/outputs.tf line 5, in output "wpl_public_subnet_ids":
        5:   value = [aws_subnet.wpl_public_subnet.*.id]
     This object does not have an attribute named "id".
```

However, everything works like charm, if I replace the output with this one:

```
aws_subnet.wpl_public_subnet.0.id
```

How could I output all subnet ids values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `for_each`, you will have a map, not a list. Thus, you have to get [values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/values.html) first, before getting the `id`s. Also you don't need extra square brackets:

```
output "wpl_public_subnet_ids" {
  value = values(aws_subnet.wpl_public_subnet)[*].id
}
```